# Stop-Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-runbook

While Stop integration runtime using powershell script command

i am getting error : Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed'

And
While downgrade app service plan basic to free i am getting error as Conflict
Command:

i want pause the integration runtime and downgrade the app service plan basic to free
Integration type is : Azure
I tried this command for pause the integration runtime:

```
Stop-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -ResourceGroupName 'rg-test-dfv2' -DataFactoryName 'test-df' -Name 'test-reserlved-ir'
```

for downgrade command:

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'app-service-plan' -ResourceGroupName 'Resource-Group-Name' -Tier Free -WorkerSize Small
```

Answer (score 0):

> Stop-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime - Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed'

**You can't start or stop the Aure IR or Self Hosted IR you can only stop Azure SSIS IR.**

- Azure IR : no way to start/stop billing based on activity/dataflow run/debug.
- Self-Hosted IR : no way to start/stop billing based on activity run.
- Azure-SSIS IR : start/stop via Portal and azure CLI/Shell billing based on SSIS package execution

If you are trying `Stop-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime` this PowerShell command on Aure IR or Self Hosted IR it will throw an error.

> And While downgrade app service plan basic to free i am getting error as Conflict

The error you are facing because of `NumberofWorkers` are more than expected. to resolve it try below command.

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'pdstackserviceplan' -ResourceGroupName 'RS-Group_name' -Tier Free -WorkerSize Small -NumberofWorkers 1
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: still same issue for the app service

Comment: have you tries to change the tier using portal and for that can you add error if you are getting?